# Python - bin sizes of lowest variance for classification

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

I would like to change my feature 'Age' from a continuous variable, to a categorical variable of age ranges for binary classification, like this:

```
df['Age'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], [0,6,12,16,65,90] ,labels=['0-6','6-12','12-16','16-65','65-90'])
```

However I want to split it in the optimal way, so that the data can be classified most efficiently. i.e the variance of classes within the age ranges is minimised while not overfitting.

Is there a package which has a method, that can minimise variance when splitting data like this, or do I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `sklearn.cluster` to do this.